# On the limit of a Minkowski sum

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Consider an open set $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

I am wondering if the set $$ \mathcal{S} := \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}  \ \mathcal{O} + \frac{1}{k} \mathbb{B} $$

is open or closed.

With $\mathbb{B}$ I mean the closed unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Everything is meant in the standard Euclidean setting (topology, metric, etc.). The sum in the definition is the standard [Minkowski sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition).

I guess that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{k} \mathbb{B} = \{0\}$, but I do not know if this is enough to claim that $\mathcal{S}$ is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a point $x$ in the closure $\overline{\mathcal O}$ of $\mathcal O$.

Which of the sets $\mathcal O + \dfrac1k\Bbb B$ contain $x$?

What about points $y$ that are a positive distance away from $\mathcal O$?

---

For further thought, try to work out what the result is if we replace $\Bbb B$ by the *open* unit ball.

Comment: I guess all the mentioned sets contain $x$, so seems $\mathcal{S}$ is closed.

Comment: It only shows $\overline{\mathcal O} \subseteq \mathcal S$. You still have to derive equality (which is where the $y$s come in) to conclude $\mathcal S$ is closed by virtue of equalling $\overline{\mathcal O}$.